# convert float to int if no decimal part

Tags: php

i want to convert float to int if there is no decimal part. and if there is decimal part i want to be up to two digits. how do i check if there is a decimal part or not?

so i have data like  this.

```
1.0000
2.0000
3.0000
9.8400
7.3200
8.0000
```

i want output like this

```
1
2
3
9.84 round to two digits if there is decimal part
7.32
8
```

is there a built function in php to know that the float has decimal part or not ?  how do i do that in php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the `printf` answer, but you can check if the number is equal to the integer cast of the number:

```
if( ($int = (int)$number) == $number) {
    $number = $int;
} else {
    $number = round($number, 2);
}
```

If you actually want 2 decimal places regardless then use `number_format`.

Comment: Not sure if `if( (int)$number == $number) {    $number = (int)$number;` looks better logic.

Answer (score 2):

you can use printf with g-flag [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

```
<?php
$arr = [
    1.0000,
    2.0000,
    3.0000,
    9.8400,
    7.3200,
    8.0000,
];

foreach ($arr as $i) {
    printf("%.4g\n", $i);
}
```

if you want to have them as vars - sprintf can be used so

```
<?php
$arr = [
    1.0000,
    2.0000,
    3.0000,
    9.8400,
    7.3200,
    8.0000,
];

$output = [];

foreach ($arr as $i) {
    $output[] = sprintf("%.4g", $i);
}

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: i dont want to print them like that im fetching those number from a query one by one i want to convert them.

Comment: @TauseefAhmad ha, so you can use - sprintf :)